# how do I disable modules in commerce kickstart

Tags: 7, commerce

I thought I needed dashboard and block languages modules for blocks. I enabled them and now want to disable them again but the update button has been replaced with an install button on the site settings -> modules admin page. How do I disable them?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: it never says install/uninstall... should say save configuration. Unless... are you in the Uninstall tab? You need to be in the List tab and just uncheck them and save config. This is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Maarten, Thanks very much - I had not noticed that button as it is located off screen, below the left hand region. You solved my problem.

Comment: This is very closely related to this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189080/how-to-disable-all-commerce-modules-from-commerce-kickstart-using-drush/189101#189101

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down to bottom of left column for save button.

A module worth mentioning is https://www.drupal.org/project/module_filter. It makes the module page a lot more user friendly.